# UIPageViewController within a UIScrollView appears fullscreen even though CGRect is set - returns to correct frame values as soon as user scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a **UIPageViewController** named ***SwipingPhotosController*** where the user swipes horizontally to view images. I have implemented this ***SwipingPhotosController*** within a **UIScrollView** by giving it **CGRect** values. Then I write a function that basically does the **stretchy header effect** of zooming in & out when the user scrolls up or down.

Everything works except that when I tried to **add another view beneath the *SwipingPhotosController***, as soon as  the controller is loaded, the image appears **full screen**. As soon as I scroll slightly, it all returns to the accurate position.

This is what I get when I press run in simulator - a full screen blown out pageviewcontroller:

[image]

Here the view goes back to normal as soon as I scroll slightly

[image]

Note: This bug occurs only when I add the nameLabel beneath the imageView (swipingPhotosController.view)

```
class ProfileController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var user: User! {
        didSet{
            swipingPhotosController.user = user
        }
    }

    lazy var scrollProfileView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.delegate = self
        sv.backgroundColor = TDGSettings
        sv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        sv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        return sv
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()

    let swipingPhotosController = SwipingPhotosController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = TDGSettings
        setupViews()
    }

    fileprivate func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(scrollProfileView)
        scrollProfileView.fillSuperview()

        let imageView = swipingPhotosController.view!
        scrollProfileView.addSubview(imageView)

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterialDark)
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
        visualEffectView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)

        scrollProfileView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.anchor(top: imageView.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16))
        nameLabel.text = "First Name"
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let imageView = swipingPhotosController.view!
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
    }

    //STRETCHY HEADER EFFECT
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let changeY = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
        var width = view.frame.width + changeY * 2
        width = max(view.frame.width, width)
        let imageView = swipingPhotosController.view!
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: min(0, -changeY), y: min(0, -changeY), width: width, height: width)
    }
}
```

As requested added code for SwipingPhotosController

```
import Foundation
import LBTATools

class SwipingPhotosController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var user: User! {
        didSet{
            controllers = user.swipingUrls.map({ (url) -> UIViewController in
                let photoController = PhotosController(imageUrl: url)
                return photoController
            })
            setViewControllers([controllers.first!], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    var controllers = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = self.controllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == viewController}) ?? 0
        if index == 0 {return nil}
        return controllers[index - 1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = self.controllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == viewController}) ?? 0
        if index == controllers.count - 1 {return nil}
        return controllers[index + 1]
    }
}


class PhotosController: UIViewController {

    let imageView = UIImageView()

    init(imageUrl: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: imageUrl){
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
        }
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.fillSuperview()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the source for your `SwipingPhotosController`? Difficult to try and see what's going on without that...

Comment: @DonMag Sure will do that now

Comment: @DonMag Hello...I have added the controller code as requested

Comment: OK - where are you setting `user` in `SwipingPhotosController`?

Comment: @DonMag Actually forgot to add that in profile controller. Thought it would be irrelevant for the current bug so emitted that code. So when profile controller initialises SwipingPhotosController, I also pass the user object from profile to swipingphotos. Didn't think it was important though as the bug is UI related.

Comment: @DonMag: I have added the code for your reference. Check out the first few lines of ProfileController class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `swipingPhotosController`'s frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` --- but the views have not yet been laid out.

You need to do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (***did*** not ***will***).

However, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` gets called many times, particularly since you are changing the frame again in `scrollViewDidScroll()`.

So, you need to set a flag to only set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` once (or again, if the scrollView frame has changed).

Not being sure how or when you were setting your `SwipingPhotosController`'s properties, I did it this way to test:

```
// add a class property
var savedScrollViewWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if scrollProfileView.frame.width != savedScrollViewWidth {
        savedScrollViewWidth = scrollProfileView.frame.width
        let imageView = swipingPhotosController.view!
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
    }

}
```

See if that gets your layout working correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it out. Just another clarification, should I also add the other subviews that I want to add in viewDidLayoutSubviews? Or can that code stay in view did load. I am talking about nameLabel in this case

Comment: @Archid - in general, do NOT add subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Add them in `viewDidLoad()` ... also set constraints in `viewDidLoad()`. The only time you need to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is when you are setting frame values that are dependent on having the other views already in place. With what you are doing, you may even be better off setting constraints on `swipingPhotosController.view` and then updating the `.constant` value for the height in `scrollViewDidScroll()`

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks a lot. Still needs some testing though and I'll update this post if there are any UI bugs related to this. But I guess yes the problem is fixed